# What are some of the most efficient ways to make a list of homogeneous transformation matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

I want a list of 4X4 matrices that follow this form:

```
a # An array of shape [n,3]

[[cos(a[0]),-sin(a[0]),0,a[1]],
[sin(a[0]),cos(a[0]),0,a[2]],
[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1]])
```

Comment: `np.mat('[1 2;3 4]')` gives you matrix object

Comment: What list comprehension do you think is "clunky and slow"?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000000
a = np.random.rand(n, 3)

c = np.cos(a[:, 0])
s = np.sin(a[:, 0])
dx = a[:, 1]
dy = a[:, 2]
z = np.zeros(n)
o = np.ones(n)

out = np.array([
    [c, -s,  z, dx],
    [s,  c,  z, dy],
    [z,  z,  o,  z],
    [z,  z,  z,  o],
]).transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Just didn't know how to put it in words.